# Add multiple categories for articles

Tags: php, laravel

I need to add several categories for a new article. I will write down everything I do in order:

**migration of categories**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blog_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->BigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title', 128);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**migration of articles**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->BigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title', 128);
            $table->string('slug', 64);
            $table->string('subtitle', 256)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**creating another migration `article_blog_category_table`**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_blog_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('blog_category_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('blog_category_id')
                ->references('id')->on('blog_categories')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('article_id')
                ->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

**Doing `belongsToMany` in models**

**article model**

```
public function blog_categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\BlogCategory');
    }
```

**category model**

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Article');
    }
}
```

Next, I write the function for adding an article in the controller (I think there is no need to write the function for adding a category, everything is clear there)

**Articles controller**

```
public static function saveArticle(Request $request) {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'blog_category_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'title' => 'required|max:128',
            'slug' => 'required|unique:articles|max:64',
            'subtitle' => 'max:256',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => $validator->errors()->first()
            ], 422);
        }

        $article = new Article();

        $blog_category = BlogCategory::where('id', $request->blog_category_id)->first();

        if(!$blog_category){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Blog category not found'
                ], 404);
        }

        $article->blog_category_id = $request->blog_category_id;
        $article->title = $request->title;
        $article->slug = $request->slug;
        $article->subtitle = $request->subtitle;

        $article->save();

        return Article::where('slug', $article->slug)->first();
    }
```

I have a method in the function to add one category. The question of how to add here so that you can add several categories, I cannot figure it out. You need something like `$article->blog_categories()->attach($request->blog_category_id);` but how to apply it correctly?

Comment: `$request->blog_category_id` is  single id or array?

Comment: @Faizan Ali single id, this is my old method for adding one category

Comment: you can pass an array of id's in attach method, if you want to insert more than categories

Comment: How can you do this? @Faizan Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming convention is complicating your task.

Rename table in categories migration:

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Also for simplicity, rename the joint (pivot) table

```
Schema::create('article_category', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // You don't need a table id here
    $table->foreignId('category_id')->index();
    $table->foreignId('article_id')->index();
    $table->unique(['article_id', 'category_id']);
    // You also don't need timestamps
});
```

Defining relationships in the models:

```
// Article model
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Category::class);
}

// Category model
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Article::class);
}
```

Article controller

```
public function store() // No need to make the function static
{
    $data = validator(request()->all(), [
        // To save many categories, send them as an array   
        'categories' => 'array',
        'categories.*' => [\Illuminate\Validation\Rule::exists('categories', 'id')], // Checks if category id is in the db
        'title' => 'required|max:128',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:articles|max:64',
        'subtitle' => 'string',
    ])->validate();

    $article = Article::create(
        \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except($data, 'categories');
    );

    // Save categories
    $article->categories()->attach($data['categories']);

    return $article;
}
```

Comment: I add the values ​​`1, 2` to the category field and get the error `"message": "The categories must be an array."` What format should you enter?

Comment: Make sure your input name has an array next to it `<input name="categories[]" />`

Comment: now I'm doing this `"message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'article_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into 'article_category' ('article_id', 'category_id') values (?, 1, 2))",`

Comment: article id should be formed immediately after the creation of the article

Comment: After you create the article as I showed above, then use the article to save the categories `$article->categories()->attach($data['categories']);`

Comment: I didn't quite get it, should I have two practically identical functions?

Comment: I do not quite understand how the article should be created first, so I have one function for the whole `saveArticle`, how can I divide it into creating an article and saving categories? @bryceandy

Comment: Look at the last piece of code I wrote `public function store`. Replace your `saveArticle` with the `store` function

Comment: I already have saveArticle specified in all routes, can't you just add several categories in the same function?

Comment: Then whatever you see in my `store` put inside your `saveArticle`

Comment: OK, I understood it, but now I have an error that the rest of the fields are not filled in, how can I fill in and save the rest of the fields right away?

Comment: What are the fields? And what does the error say?

Comment: well, here is the slug field `"The slug has already been taken."`

Comment: I filled it in like this `$article->slug = $request->slug;` and then `$article->save();` , 
now it turns out that the field is not filled

Comment: This line `$article = Article::create(
        \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except($data, 'categories');
    );` is already creating the article. You dont need to create it again

Comment: I understood, but how to fill in the fields now, here they are even indicated in the validation: title, slug, subtitle

Comment: Are you having validaton errors? And what do they say?

Comment: yes, I have an error in validation, because these fields are empty and not filled in any way

Comment: Then the problem is how you submit the fields from the form to the controller. Do you have a name & required attribute for every field? For example `<input name="subtitle" required/>`

Comment: I'm still without a front, I'm testing through postman, I have `categories [], title, slug, subtitle` fields, all these fields are in validation: `'title' => 'required|max:128',
        'slug' => 'required|unique:articles|max:64',
        'subtitle' => 'string',`, but in the store function itself, only the category field is filled

Comment: I fill in the `categories [], title, slug, subtitle` fields in the postman but get a validation error as it only accepts the categories field

Comment: I understood everything, but now I have a different error ` "message": "SQLSTATE[01000]: Warning: 1265 Data truncated for column 'category_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `article_category` (`article_id`, `category_id`) values (4, 1, 2))",`

Comment: In postman send categories with `categories[0] = firstCategory`, `categories[1] = secondCategory`, `categories[2] = thirdCategory` etc

Comment: seems to work, thanks a lot for the help))

Answer (score 0):

According to Documentation
[Many To Many Relationships
Attaching / Detaching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

```
//You can pass an array of id's categories in attach method:
$article->blog_categories()->attach($categories_ids_array);

/* 
*if you want to pass more columns value you can pass an associative array of 
*column names with their values e.g attach($categories ids array, an array of 
*more columns with their values)
*/

$article->blog_categories()->attach($categories_ids_array, ['column_name' => 
$column_values]);
```